# Error making http request in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kannel

I am trying to make an http request to send and sms through kannel using ruby but its not working,what could be the problem with the code in this method. Thanx

```
require 'net/http'

 def self.send_sms( to, from, message)
   id = rand(36**8).to_s(36)
   uri= URI('http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?')
   params = {username: 'skylinesms', password: 'password', from: '#{from}', 
             text: '#{message}', 
             'dlr-url': '#{Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.deliver_url(:id => id)}',
             'dlr-mask': 3
            }
   uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
   req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.to_s)
   res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
   res
 end
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Do you get any kind of error message in the logs ( or console if you are running from there? ) Can you send an SMS directly though that url if you just make the same request manually?

Comment: @glenatron sms can be sent manually and this is part of background work sent to sidekiq which it processes successfully. Am more worried about the code.

Comment: ^ Let's talk about Ruby. Please read the [ruby-style-guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide). It is super helpful. I see a number of divergences from Ruby standards. [(1) Your variable names are not descriptive.](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming) (2) You are using a return statement when it is not required. (3) Your hash is formatted awkwardly. Put each of those entries on a new line. Again, see the style guide. Finally, welcome to Stack Overflow! Take some time to review the [how to ask good questions guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: please follow the instruction while post and maintain ruby style code

Comment: In addition to what @screenmutt said, you can't interpolate values with single-quoted strings. For example, `'#{from}'` should instead be written as `"#{from}"`, `from.to_s` or preferably just `from` assuming it's already a string.